# Stop macro if date not found

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I need to search a date in a column and if not found stop the macro. The date comes from a Cell

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = Worksheets("Calculations").Cells(4, 3).Value
MyInput.Activate
Set rng1 = Range("H:H").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
'Macro follows
Else
    MsgBox "Date not found"
End If
End Sub
```

What this macro does is always returns the message box even if date is there.

Thanks

Comment: because the Find failed

Comment: date is a number value rather than a string. try convert it into a number using DateValue

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to look for a date as a string type.
I just changed the strSearch to dteSearch with a Date type.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim dteSearch As Date
dteSearch = Worksheets("Calculations").Cells(4, 3).Value
MyInput.Activate
Set rng1 = Range("H:H").Find(dteSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
'Macro follows
Else
    MsgBox "Date not found"
End If
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. It solves my problem partly. I have a microsoft date picker in another sheet. If I select date "3/9/2016", it works, but if I select any other date, it still says date not found even if that date is there.

Comment: Datepicker will return a date serial number. if in your H Row does contains some text formatted dates, this will not work obviousely as it's expecting to compare numbers. You can try the formatting feature of Find method. but to be sure, it's safer to have the dates in the right format on your H row. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Or you could try a VBA loop like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531137/vba-goto-cell-with-a-certain-value-type-date/35531503#35531503

Comment: Thanks Ambie, that's a great link you shared!