# Search Engine with Criteria Between 2 date Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search-engine

i try to make a search enggine using vba excel and found a code like this

```
Sub Search1()
    Dim sCol As String
    Dim rgFind As Range, rgData As Range, rgCell As Range
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim vCrit As Variant

    Range(Range("m8"), Range("m8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
    sCol = Range("n3").Value
    Set rgFind = Range("a2:j2").Find(sCol, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    iCol = rgFind.Column
    lRow = Range("a2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    vCrit = Range("n5").Value
    Set rgData = Range(Cells(3, iCol), Cells(lRow, iCol))
    For Each rgCell In rgData
        Set rgFind = rgCell.Find(vCrit, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rgFind Is Nothing Then
            Range(Cells(rgCell.Row, 1), Cells(rgCell.Row, 10)).Copy
            Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next rgCell
    Range("n5").Select 
End Sub
```

but this script only search data that contain alphabet and number on field that i was search.

but i want to search data between 2 date. i choose the field i want to search ( field with date data ) and search the data between 2 date.

here the file 
https://mega.nz/#!y5ZHFKIY!OpHpyKuorC0iHVlOGZW0g-qXfNAv9GxL0wyBpN45sLE

i already try to change the script using

```
rSearch = Sheet1.Range("B3", Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
'search data in range B3 - B (contain data date) and then using change the if 
if rSearch >= Date1 Or rSearch <= Date2
```

but got error type mismatch or something 
can someone help me so i can search the data between 2 date 
thanks before

Comment: type mismatch means they both are of different data type hence can't be compared. convert them to a single data type before comparison. Use `CDate` to convert them to Date data type. Also use `.Value2` for assignment purpose wherever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

i try to change it like this and still get error missmatch

```
Sub Cari()
    Dim sCol As String
    Dim rgFind As Range, rgData As Range, rgCell As Range
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim vCrit As Date
    Dim vCrit1 As Date
    Dim rSearch As Range
```

```
Range(Range("m8"), Range("m8").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).ClearContents
sCol = Range("n3").Value
Set rgFind = Range("a2:j2").Find(sCol, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
iCol = rgFind.Column
lRow = Range("a2").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
vCrit = CDate(Range("N5"))
vCrit1 = CDate(Range("N6"))
Set rgData = Range(Cells(3, iCol), Cells(lRow, iCol))
Set rSearch = Sheet1.Range("E10", Sheet1.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each rgCell In rgData
    'Set rgFind = rgCell.Find(vCrit, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    'If Not rgFind Is Nothing Then
    If rSearch >= vCrit Or rSearch <= vCrit1 Then
        Range(Cells(rgCell.Row, 1), Cells(rgCell.Row, 10)).Copy
        Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next rgCell
Range("n5").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when using `.Find` with dates: define the search date with the `CDate` function and make sure the date format matches Excel's default setting. See this post for further details: [VBA, goto cell with a certain value (type: date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531137/vba-goto-cell-with-a-certain-value-type-date/35531503#35531503)

You'll see from the post that I prefer to search for dates using pure VBA and the `.Value2` property. This property gives dates in their Excel `Long` values which means the property doesn't change with date format. The advantage is that user fiddling with formats, etc. can't upset your search engine. It also means you can set more complex matching criteria, such as a date within a date range or omitting specific days.

Below is an example of how a pure VBA search engine could work for you. You'll have to adjust the data parameters to suit your own `Worksheet` but I'm hoping the comments will explain each step for you. Make sure you run this in a brand new `Workbook` because it writes some sample data on Sheet1:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SearchDate()
    Dim dataRng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim date2 As Date
    Dim dateVal1 As Long
    Dim dateVal2 As Long
    Dim found As Boolean

    'Write some sample data to the worksheet -
    CreateSampleData ' call this routine just once

    'Read the data into a variant array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(3, "B"), .Cells(r, "C"))
        v = dataRng.Value2
    End With

    'Set some sample dates
    date1 = #1/20/2016#
    date2 = #2/20/2016#

    'Convert the dates to Excel's date values
    dateVal1 = CLng(date1)
    dateVal2 = CLng(date2)

    'Loop through the dates to find the first within the date range
    found = False
    For r = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
        If v(r, 1) >= dateVal1 And v(r, 1) <= dateVal2 Then
            MsgBox v(r, 2)
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not found Then MsgBox "No date."

End Sub

Private Sub CreateSampleData()
    Dim sample(1 To 101, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim dateVal As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    'Create some sample data where
    'column B has 100 dates and
    'column C has a string simulating the data.
    'This will write the data to "Sheet1" so make sure
    'you use a new workbook.

    sample(1, 1) = "Date"
    sample(1, 2) = "Item"
    dateVal = DateSerial(2016, 1, 1)
    For i = 2 To 101
        sample(i, 1) = dateVal
        sample(i, 2) = "Day " & i - 1 & " data"
        dateVal = dateVal + 1
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") _
        .Range("B2:C102").value = sample

End Sub
```