# VBA - Find next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

Good day, I am newbie in VBA programming. need some help from experts :)

After i enter the date and click the generate button the code will find the date on the excel, but im done with this problem and here are my codes..

```
        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim FindDate As Date

        FindDate = txtDate.Value

        If Trim(FindDate) <> "" Then
            With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B")
                Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindDate, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)

                    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                        Application.Goto Rng, True
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Nothing found"
                    End If
            End With
        End If
```

My next problem is, i need to select the empty cell next to the date.. Here is a screen shot

[image]

Comment: When the date is found, 'Rng' will be set to the cell where the match is. You can reference 'rng.Row' and 'rng.Column' if you want to see the values, or just use something like Cells(rsg.row, rng.column).value = "Look to the left".  Or you can use an 'Offset' to 'rng'.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, the simplest way would be:

```
Rng.Offset(, 1).Select
```

However, you ought to be aware that the `Find()` function when using dates can be a little unreliable. See this post for more info and links: [VBA, goto cell with a certain value (type: date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531137/vba-goto-cell-with-a-certain-value-type-date/35531503#35531503). Your case is particularly exposed to risk as the date is entered via a `TextBox`.

I have to say your code looks awfully similar to the OP's of that post. You really ought to credit code sources if you didn't write it yourself.

If I were you, I'd convert your textbox value to a `Long` and then search the cell values (using  the `.Value2` property which provides date values as Longs) for the matching Long. Code isn't much longer and could look like this:

```
Dim src As Range
Dim findDate As Date
Dim findVal As Long
Dim cell As Range

'Define the source data range
With Sheet2
    Set src = .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
End With

'Acquire search date and convert to long
findDate = CDate(UserForm1.txtDate.Value)
findVal = CLng(findDate)

'Search for date
For Each cell In src.Cells
    If cell.Value2 = findVal Then
        Application.Goto cell, True
        'Select the next cell to the right
        cell.Offset(, 1).Select
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you could

- use a `Function` to try returning the wanted range

  ```
  Function SetRange(FindDate As Date) As Range
      If Trim(FindDate) <> "" And IsDate(FindDate) Then
          With Sheets("Sheet2") '<--| reference wanted sheet
              With .Range("B1", .cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "B" range from row 1 down to last not empty row
                  On Error Resume Next '<--| if subsequent 'Find()' avoid possible subsequent statement error to stop the Function
                  Set SetRange = .Find(What:=FindDate, After:=.cells(.cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Offset(, 1) '<--| try finding the passed 'FindDate' in referenced range and offset 1 column to the right
              End With
          End With
      End If
  End Function
  ```
- and have your "Main" sub check it against `Nothing` before using it:

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Sub Main()
      Dim Rng As Range

      Set Rng = SetRange(txtDate.Text)
      If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.Select
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: @BartD, if my answer solves your question then please accept it by   clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Comment: @BartD, any chance to get feedback from you?