# Unable to find date using VBA .find

Tags: excel, vba

`tmpArr(1, j)` may be a date or a string. If it is a date then I need to find it in Range(i4:ck4). The dates in this range are formatted as dates. My code below is not finding my dates. What am I doing wrong?

`Data` is Code in column A which is alphanumeric and may be 3 characters long. `Tbk mnth` is column B and is a date.

```
Code    Tbk Mnth
BX      1-Oct-06
C7      1-Dec-11
C7      1-Apr-12
LA      1-Feb-15
NJ      1-Mar-15
```

```vb
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmpArr As Variant
    Dim Dict As Object, tmpDict As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v, key
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim d As Date

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Plan")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("test")

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 2))

        tmpArr = rng.Value

        For i = LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1)
            ' Test if value exists in dictionary. If not add and set up the dictionary item
            If Not Dict.exists(tmpArr(i, 1)) Then
                Set tmpDict = Nothing
                Set tmpDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                Dict.Add key:=tmpArr(i, 1), item:=tmpDict
            End If
            ' Set nested dictionary to variable to edit it
            Set tmpDict = Nothing
            Set tmpDict = Dict(tmpArr(i, 1))

            ' Test if value exists in nested Dictionary, add if not and initiate counter
            If Not tmpDict.exists(tmpArr(i, 2)) Then
                tmpDict.Add key:=tmpArr(i, 2), item:=1
            Else
                ' Increment counter if it already exists
                tmpDict(tmpArr(i, 2)) = tmpDict(tmpArr(i, 2)) + 1
            End If
            ' Write nested Dictionary back to Main dictionary
            Set Dict(tmpArr(i, 1)) = tmpDict
        Next i

        ' Repurpose array for output setting to maximum possible size (helps with speed of code)
        ReDim tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2), LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1))
        ' Set starting counters for array
        i = LBound(tmpArr, 1)
        j = LBound(tmpArr, 2)
        ' Convert dictionary and nested dictionary to flat output
        For Each key In Dict
            tmpArr(j, i) = key
            i = i + 1
            For Each v In Dict(key)
                tmpArr(j, i) = v
                tmpArr(j + 1, i) = Dict(key)(v)
                i = i + 1
            Next v
        Next key

        ' Reshape array to actual size
        ReDim Preserve tmpArr(LBound(tmpArr, 1) To UBound(tmpArr, 1), LBound(tmpArr, 2) To i - 1)
        'Change dates less than date in cell 1,9  to overdue and find the row number associated to the code
        d = ws.Cells(1, 9).Value
        For j = LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2)
            dte = tmpArr(1, j)
            If dte < d Then
                tmpArr(1, j) = "Overdue"
                b = b + tmpArr(2, j)
            Else
                With ws2.Range("e5:e280")
                    Set c = .find(tmpArr(1, j), LookIn:=xlValues)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        firstAddress = Mid(firstAddress, 4, 3)
                        tmpArr(2, j) = firstAddress
                    End If
                End With
            End If    
        Next j

        For j = LBound(tmpArr, 2) To UBound(tmpArr, 2)
            l = Len(tmpArr(1, j))
            Select Case l
            Case Is <= 3
                k = j
                rw = tmpArr(2, k)
            Case 7
                With ws2.Cells(rw, 8)
                    .Value = .Value + tmpArr(2, j)
                End With
            Case 10
                'find column for date numbers
                With ws2.Range("I4:CK4")
                    d = tmpArr(1, j)
                    Set c = .find(DateValue(Format(CDate(d), "dd/mm/yyyy")), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    Debug.Print d
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        firstAddress = Mid(firstAddress, 4, 3)
                    End If                
                End With
            End Select
        Next j

        'See what  tmpArr looks like
        With ws3.Cells(2, 5)
            Range(.Offset(0, 0), .Cells(UBound(tmpArr, 2), UBound(tmpArr, 1))) = Application.Transpose(tmpArr)
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is d set as date format in your sheet ?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531137/vba-goto-cell-with-a-certain-value-type-date/35531503#35531503. Could be the cause of your problems.

Comment: Inside the `select case : case 10`, what is `TypeName(tmpArr(1, j))`?

Comment: @GSerg  d = tmpArr(1, j)  tmpArr(1, j) is the date I am trying to find in range  ws2.Range("I4:CK4")

Comment: Yes, and what is its `TypeName()`?

Comment: @GSerg  MyType = TypeName(d) Mytype = "Date"

Comment: Then `.find(DateValue(Format(CDate(d), "dd/mm/yyyy")), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)` should be `.Find(d, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`.

Comment: @GSerg Set c = .find(d, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) doesn't find the date! when I debug xlValues = -4163  xlWhole = 1

Comment: You do not need to debug `xlValues` or `xlWhole` You do however need to verify that `ws2.Range("I4:CK4")` contains dates that are formatted as dates (again, with `TypeName`).

Comment: @GSerg mytype = TypeName(ws2.Cells(4, 41).Value) mytype = "Date"

Comment: Do those dates have a time component (seen in the formula bar when the cell is selected)? Do the dates in `Tbk Mnth` have a time component?

Comment: @GSerg they have no time component.

Comment: Then there is no reason why it would not find them. Can you make a separate xslx file that shows the problem, with a small portion of the `Tbk Mnth` data and a small portion of `ws2.Range("I4:CK4")`, and upload it somewhere?

Comment: @GSerg Really appreciate your time. Can you recommend somewhere I can upload the file or long shot I am happy to e-mail it.

Comment: Google drive would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use : `DateValue()` if your **date** d is set as date format in cells then delete `CDate()` because `Cdate()` is used to convert  `String` to `date`

```
Case 10
            With ws2.Range("i4:ck4")
            Dim d As Date
                d = tmpArr(1, j)
                    Set c = .find(DateValue(CDate(d)), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = c.Address
                    firstAddress = Mid(firstAddress, 4, 3)

                    End If

            End With

        End Select
    Next j
```

So if your **cell is as date format** maybe use this one :

```
Case 10
            With ws2.Range("i4:ck4")
            Dim d As Date
                d = tmpArr(1, j)
                    Set c = .find(DateValue(d), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = c.Address
                    firstAddress = Mid(firstAddress, 4, 3)

                    End If

            End With

        End Select
    Next j
```

**Edit**

```
Case 10
                With ws2.Range("i4:ck4")
                Dim d As Date
                    d = tmpArr(1, j)
                        Set c = .find(DateValue(Format(CDate(d), "dd/mm/yyyy")), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                        If Not c Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = c.Address
                        firstAddress = Mid(firstAddress, 4, 3)

                        End If

                End With

            End Select
        Next j
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have tried both your solutions but no success. The array is built up from cells that are formatted as date so d should be a date. When I debug the line Set c = .find(DateValue(d), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)   d = 2018/10/01 xlValues = -4163 xlPart = 2 . Should the value for 2018/10/01 not be 43374?

Comment: Appreciate your help but still no luck!

Comment: @Anthony Can you Debug.Print `DateValue(Format(CDate(d), "dd/mm/yyyy")` Just after `d = tmp(i,j)` So we see what It does..

Comment: Values stay the same:  d = 2018/10/01 xlValues = -4163 xlPart = 2

Comment: @ Dorian debug.Print  d = 2018/10/01

Comment: @Anthony after `d ) tmp(1,J)` add : `debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(CDate(d)).Row` This should give you the first row where we found the date

Comment: @Anthony so d = 20/18/01 and what is writen in your cell 2018/10/01 or 01/10/2018 or smth else ?

Comment: The date I am trying to find is in cell is in AK4 and is date formatted and looks like this 2018/10/01. I actually only need the column number. When I try this: Debug.Print ws2.Range("AK:AK").find(CDate(d)).Row  I receive error 91 object variable with block variable not set.

Comment: What is a UTS value?

Comment: @Anthony `Sheets("Name").Range("AK:AK").Find("2018/10/01").Row` Replace Name by your sheet name

Comment: Tried:  Debug.Print Sheets("Plan").Range("AK:AK").find(2018 / 10 / 1).Row  Still receive error 91

Comment: @Anthony add `""` for the date : Debug.Print `Sheets("Plan").Range("AK:AK").find("2018 / 10 / 1").Row`

Comment: you are indeed patient! Appreciate your help. Tried that. Still error 91

Comment: wow and if you select you **AK** Column then press **Ctrl + F** Then type 2018/10/1 then search, does this found something ?

Comment: Ctrl F and 2018/10/01 is found! That is why I am baffled!

Comment: @Anthony May I Ask you to edit your issue so I can try to debug it ?

Comment: @Anthony Just Copy And Paste your full code in your issue, so I can reproduce this

Comment: I have now posted the full code. I hope it makes sense. I am a novice VBA coder.

Comment: @Anthony If your issue is solved, May I ask you to accept this answer ?