# Why is VBA Find unable to find Date values within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA Find function to search a variable of type Date within a range of Excel cells. Below is my code:

```
Public SprintDate As Date
```

In my Excel worksheet, I have cells I3 thru X3 that show dates like below. :
[image: Picture 1]

Additionally, the cells J3 thru X3 have a formula that adds 21 days to the value of I3 (see second picture below)
[image: Picture 2]

The cells J3 thru X3 are also of Date Format in Excel like below:

[image: Picture 3]

This is the code that I have to do the search:

```
                sSprintName1 = Trim(Split(JSONObj_Story("issues")(k)("fields")("customfield_10000")(JSONObj_Story("issues")(k)("fields")("customfield_10000").Count), "(+3 weeks)")(0))
                sSprintName2 = Split(sSprintName1, ",")(3)
                sSprintName3 = Split(Trim(sSprintName2), "=")(1)
                sSprintDay = Split(Trim(sSprintName3), "-")(2)
                
                sSprintName4 = Trim(Split(JSONObj_Story("issues")(k)("fields")("customfield_10000")(JSONObj_Story("issues")(k)("fields")("customfield_10000").Count), "endDate")(0))
                sSprintFullDate = Left(Split(sSprintName4, "startDate=")(1), 10) ' 2022-03-15
                sSprintMonth = Right(Left(sSprintFullDate, 7), 2)
                
                sSearchKey = sSprintMonth & "/" & sSprintDay & "/" & Year(Now())
                SprintDate = Format(sSearchKey, "m/d/yyyy")
```

Please ignore the variables (of type String) sSprintName1,sSprintName2, sSprintName3, sSprintName4. They are being used to extract Month and Date values from the JSON response.

Here is the Find function code that I have:

```
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Roadmap").Range("G3:X3").Find(SprintDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I have searched on this site and found some similar questions but I am afraid they have not helped me much:

Resources from here:

[Unable to find date using VBA .find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285764/unable-to-find-date-using-vba-find)

[VBA, goto cell with a certain value (type: date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531137/vba-goto-cell-with-a-certain-value-type-date/35531503#35531503)

Comment: what is the actual value of `SprintDate`?

Comment: @jsotola - The value of SprintDate is  2/1/2022

Comment: as I recall, simple `find`, does find only raw date value, but fails to find any date-related formulas even if you have, `xlFormulas`, or `xlValues` options in the function...
Please let me know if I am wrong, - will adjust one old script I created. :)

Comment: @VBasic2008 Probably want to look in xlValues. But certainly you need to convert SprintDate to a an Excel Date.

Comment: @DS_London: You are right, it has to be `Worksheets("Roadmap").Range("G3:X3").Find(DateSerial(Year(Date), CLng(sSprintMonth), CLng(sSprintDay)), , xlValues, xlWhole)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Application.Match* vs *Find* With Dates

```vb
sSearchKey = sSprintMonth & "/" & sSprintDay & "/" & Year(Date)
Dim SprintDate As Date
SprintDate = CDate(sSearchKey)

Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Worksheets("Roadmap").Range("G3:X3")

' The Find Method

' The Find method will fail:
' when the worksheet is filtered,
' when there are hidden rows or columns (when 'xlValues'),
' and when there are merged cells (possibly your case).
Set rng1 = rg.Find(SprintDate, , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rng1.Address(0, 0), rng1.Value
Else
    Debug.Print "Nope."
End If

' The Application.Match Function

Dim dIndex As Variant
dIndex = Application.Match(CLng(SprintDate), rg, 0)
If IsNumeric(dIndex) Then
    Set rng1 = rg.Cells(dIndex)
    Debug.Print dIndex, rng1.Address(0, 0), rng1.Value
Else
    Debug.Print "Nope."
End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I have modified per the above suggestion and I accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Roadmap").Range("G3:X3").Find(DateSerial(Year(Date), CLng(sSprintMonth), CLng(sSprintDay)), , xlValues, xlWhole)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?